# join two Oracle tables, date to not overlapping date ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-optimization

I have two tables:

- trips:  id_trip, id_object, trip_date, delta (8980026 rows)
- ranges: id_range, id_object, date_since, date_until (18490 rows)

I need to optimize the following select statement

```
  select r.id_range, sum(t.delta) sum_deltas
    from trips t,
         ranges r
   where t.id_object = r.id_object
     and t.trip_date between r.date_since and r.date_until
group by r.id_range
```

according to the condition there is always exactly one matching row for trip in 'ranges'

- the trips table is constantly growing, but there are no updates or deletions
- table ranges may change from time to time in any way (deletions, updates, inserts), so function based index is not the way :(
- there are indexes on id_object (in both tables) and date_since (in trips)

Does anyone have an idea how to speed things up, is it even possible?

Comment: could you give some functional explanation about the range table please¿ What is it? What kind of data is it filled up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always possible to speed things up; it just may not be worth the time / effort / money / disk-space / additional overheads etc.

Firstly please use the explicit join syntax. It's been the SQL standard for a few decades now and it helps avoid a lot of potential errors. Your query would become:

```
select r.id_range, sum(t.delta) sum_deltas
  from trips t
  join ranges r
    on t.id_object = r.id_object
   and t.trip_date between r.date_since and r.date_until
 group by r.id_range
```

This query would imply that you need two indexes - unique if possible. On `ranges` you should have an index on `id_object, date_since, date_until`. The index on `trips` would be `id_object, trip_date`. If `trips` were smaller I might consider adding `delta` on to the end of that index so you never enter the table at all but only do a index scan. As it stands you're going to have to do a table access by index rowid.

Having written all that your problem may be slightly different. You're going to be full-scanning both tables with this query. Your problem might be the *indexes*. If the optimizer is using the indexes then it's possible you're doing an index unique/range scan for each `id_object` in `trips` or `ranges` and then, because of the use of columns not in the indexes you will be doing an table access by index rowid. This can be massively expensive.

Try adding a [hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm) to force a full-scan of both tables:

```
select /*+ full(t) full(r) */ r.id_range, sum(t.delta) sum_deltas
  from trips t
  join ranges r
    on t.id_object = r.id_object
   and t.trip_date between r.date_since and r.date_until
 group by r.id_range
```

Comment: Hi Ben, your post is really interesting. I'm trying to understand your explanation: you are saying that in some cases it is better to not use the indexes at all and force a full scan, because sometimes the index is used but anyway afterwards an access by rowid is required to fullfil other conditions? Did I understand well?

Comment: @Sebas you understand perfectly! I can't know for certain whether it would be quicker or not in this case as I don't know what percentage of the tables fulfil the join conditions. However, generally at _very_roughly 10% it becomes quicker to full-scan than to use an index.

Comment: great! thanks. To finish, is it the access by rowid itself which is costly or the sum of the index scan + table-access-by-rowid scan that are superior to a single fullscan?

Comment: @Sebas, I have no idea :-). Think about it slight differently. If for each row in your 8m row table you find the row you need in the index. Then, use the rowid to find the row in the table. All of that instead of just grabbing it. I'm not saying that it would be quicker and my points on indexes may be more relevant but it's definitely worth trying.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Yes of course it depends of the tables and the infrastructure. Thank you for your explanations. rgds.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer, specially the unique index part, resolved my problem. I included **all required fields** in the **unique index** (280 MB), so oracle **does not need to select anything** from the table (>2GB) itself.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at your data segmentation (i.e. partition your data by certain dates, causing the query to only hit the appropriate partitions) and indices, these could probably speed up the querying process.

Also, you could consider a data warehouse... You say Trips never gets updated or deleted so it is an ideal candidate for denormalization into a data structure more suited to report generation and ad-hoc queries.